# jQuery add to current width

Tags: jquery, width

I need this code to, if `#vid` is present, add 855px to its current width. If not, it should do nothing. I'm not sure how to get jQuery to add to an already existing number, but I'm sure it's pretty simple. Here is the code I have so far:

```
if ($("#vid").length) {
            $("#img-container").width(+=855),
        } else {
            return false;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try this:

```
if ($("#vid").length)
{
    $("#img-container").width($("#img-container").width() + 855);
}
```

Comment: This was the best answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @steve - in which case, don't forget to make it your accepted answer :) (Green check mark to the left)

Comment: Haha I'm working on it... I had to wait 7 more minutes until I could check it. :)

Answer (score 22):

jQuerys methods do not support a `+=` syntax (only exception: `css strings`), you would need to write:

```
$("#img-container").width($("#img-container").width() + 855)
```

or

```
$("#img-container").css("width", "+=855");
```

Comment: This one was also correct, but the other one was said first. Thanks :)

Comment: This is much much better though because you avoid calling jQuery twice (every time you call a jQuery object out of a chain, i.e. $(element) you instantiate jQuery all over again)

Comment: This should have been best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just another option:

If you are wanting to animate it

```
$("#img-container").animate({width: "+=855px"});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($("#vid").length) 
{
    var currentWidth = $("#img-container").width();
    $("#img-container").css('width', currentWidth +855);
}
else 
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `#vid` is present? Do you mean if it is showing? Anyhow, you must put `+=855` in quation marks like this `"+=855px"` and try css like this:

```
if ($("#vid").css("display") != "none") {
            $("#img-container").css("width", "+=855px");
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
});
```

ALSO you must add "px".

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete this, because i only found a partly solution to my problem here. Figured out the rest by myself. If you want to increment a CSS value variably, do

```
    var makeBigger=855;
    $("#img-container").css("width", "+="+makeBigger);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#vid").length) {
            var vid = $("#img-container");
            vid.width(vid.width() + 855);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
});
```